# WordPress browse throuhh SUBcategory

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I'm working on a WP template, right now you can browse through the posts I use:

```
<?php next_post_link('%link', '>', true); ?>
<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<', true); ?>
```

But this will browse through all the posts of the main category, But when you're in a subcategory, I want it to browse to subcategory only. It now browse through posts of other subcategories as well.

How do I manage this?

Comment: take a look at third and fifth parameters of the functions next_post_link, previous_post_link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link